# How to crack rar file with protected pass with only the AES-256 key?

Tags: aes, password-cracking

I have rar with protected pass.But I have the AES-256 key can I crack it and if I can. how?

Comment: What you mean by *But I have the AES-256 key*?

Comment: XP at [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/77534/36960) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60157565/6230282)

Comment: Winrar use aes256 to encrypt the file they use the password to create the aes256 key and I dont have the pass but I have the key